# Solr Facet split string in multiple terms. How to include whitespace?

Tags: arrays, string, solr, facet, faceted-search

I'm using Solr 8.2.0, I'm indexing data in arrays to use in facets. This is an example of the facet field

```
"authors_facet":["John Smith", "Hillary Clinton"]
```

In the json response I have these facets:

```
authors_facet":[
        "john",531,
        "smith",531,
        "hillary",531,
        "clinton",531
]
```

I want instead to have facets like this:

```
authors_facet":[
        "john smith",531,
        "hillary clinton",531
]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that you use a `string` field for facets. From the look of it your `authors_facet` field is a tokenized field (like a text field) and hence you see the tokens as facets.

See also https://github.com/hectorcorrea/solr-for-newbies/blob/master/tutorial.md#facets

Comment: is there a way to disable this behaviour?

Comment: EDIT: thank you, your tutorial give me a good hint, I changed authors_facet in authors_ss and now it works as expected!